# How can I translate this Markdown with alt text into HTML with image resizing?

Tags: html, markdown

I have this Markdown code which displays an image, but does not incorporate the width element and instead prints it as plaintext (it is broken)

```
![Some alt text describing this image](https://example.com/exampleimage.png){ width=50% }
```

How can I translate this into HTML so it looks like:

```
<img src="https://example.com/exampleimage.png" width="50%">
```

but while retaining the alt text?

Comment: `<img src="https://example.com/exampleimage.png" width="50%" alt="alt text">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several different dialects and editors for **Markdown**, and they all translate into **HTML** with their own nuances. Therefore, the best solution in this case would be to use HTML code.

Markdown:

```
<img src="drawing.jpg" alt="drawing" width="50%"/>
```

OR `*.md` + `*.css`

Markdown:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="URL"/>
...
![drawing](drawing.jpg)
```

CSS:

```
img[alt=drawing] {
    width: 50%;
}
```